# Accessing authenticated Azure API APP

Tags: api, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-apps

I have an Azure API APP that I have set up to use Azure AD authentication.
Like so:

[image]

I also have a console app that have a generated client API to my API APP like this:

[image]

If I disable the authentication on the API APP, I can call the API from my console app.
If I enable the Azure AD authentication, the client can not call the API due to "not authorized" exception, which is ofcourse expected.

I have searched all over the place to find any information on how to supply credentials of the correct type to the API.
There is a `client.Credentials` property that can be either `TokenCredentials` or `BasicAuthenticationCredentials`

What would be the correct way to authenticate the client through the Azure AD if I have username and password for the AD user?

I am unable to find *any* documentation that relates to the auto generated API clients from the Azure SDK.

[Edit]
The reply from @chrisgillum leads to an article on how to do this:

```
internal class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var uri = new Uri("https://ro....azureapp.azurewebsites.net");
        var client = new LearningAzure(uri);
        client.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",
            ServicePrincipal.GetS2SAccessTokenForProdMSA().AccessToken);
        var res = client.Foo.GetById(123);
    }
}


public static class ServicePrincipal
{
    // The _authority is the issuer URL of the tenant.
    private static readonly string _authority = "https://login.windows.net/ro....ouse.onmicrosoft.com";

    // The _resource is the Client ID of the "data web api" AAD app.
    private static readonly string _resource = "b8b0.....8e3623d";

    // The Client ID of the "client" AAD app (i.e. this app).
    private static readonly string _clientId = "d25892.....33a0";

    // The key that was created for the "client" app (i.e. this app).
    private static readonly string _clientSecret = "??????";

    public static AuthenticationResult GetS2SAccessTokenForProdMSA()
    {
        return GetS2SAccessToken(_authority, _resource, _clientId, _clientSecret);
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets an application token used for service-to-service (S2S) API calls.
    /// </summary>
    private static AuthenticationResult GetS2SAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string clientId,
        string clientSecret)
    {
        // Client credential consists of the "client" AAD web application's Client ID
        // and the key that was generated for the application in the AAD Azure portal extension.
        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        // The authentication context represents the AAD directory.
        var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);

        // Fetch an access token from AAD.
        var authenticationResult = context.AcquireToken(
            resource,
            clientCredential);
        return authenticationResult;
    }
}
```

The `_clientSecret` how do I get this one? 
The client app configured in my Azure AD does not have any options to generate a secret.

Published web apps can, but my custom created native app only has a client Id on the configure page.
Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get credentials on a console app, if you are prompting for a user login, you can use their credentials to acquire a token. Otherwise, you need to use a Client App Key (which is a client App URI and matching API key) to acquire a token.

```
Uri aadUri = new Uri(_settings.AadUri);
Uri authorityUri = new Uri(aadUri, _settings.TenantUri);
string authority = authorityUri.ToString();

AuthenticationResult authorizationResult;
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new TokenCache());

var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_settings.ClientId, _settings.AppKey);
authorizationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(_settings.AppIdUri, clientCredential);
```

You also need to make sure your app URI is in the manifest for the service endpoint (or somehow provisions to give your app in azure access to the Azure AD).

Comment: Oh, the ClientId is the GUID from the portal if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Thanks, this sorted things out, I can now authenticate using both userid/pwd via code and via prompt.. thanks!

Comment: Great, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, this feature is based on the open source project AutoRest.
The source code and documentation can be found at https://github.com/Azure/autorest

On the following page, you can find an example of an authenticated request: https://github.com/Azure/autorest/blob/master/Documentation/clients-init.md

Comment: There seems to be no information on how to actually authenticate against Azure AD. the BasicAuthenticationCredentials are for as the name implies, basic authentication.. :-/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple different ways you can create a console app which authenticates with an AAD-protected API app.  Here is some documentation which shows authenticating using user credentials:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-user-principal-auth/

And here is an example of a .NET web app (client) calling into an API app using service principal credentials: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-service-principal-auth/. It's not exactly what you're asking about, but might be enough to help get you on the right track.

Comment: That article is about SSO from AngularJS / JS client in the browser

Comment: @RogerAlsing Ah, my bad. I think the next best thing would be to try this article, which shows a .NET web app (client) calling into an API app. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-service-principal-auth/

Comment: This seems to be on the right track, however, still getting unauthorized exception. see updated question, Ive added the code from the article there.