# Authorising a .net user-application through Google or Twitter

Tags: azure-api-apps

My question is [Similar to this one[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494623/accessing-authenticated-azure-api-app), but with third party providers instead of active directory.

I have an end-user UWP app, and I want to consume my Azure API App. I am NOT Azure mobile app and it's client side SDK.

Most of documentation is of sort "copy paste this magic code" and never explains how authentication actually happens.

I was inspecting mobile app SDK because Microsoft's documentation says that it's auth. process is the same.
 From what I see, the mobile App SDK opens a web-view very similar to that produced by a [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227025). Then every request to the server is accompanied by a header X-ZUMO-AUTH and a token. It appears that this token is issued by the azure app service, not the original provider. It is much longer than the tokens issued by Twitter or Google.
At the same time when I point web-browser at the end-point and go through the log-in process, I see that the browser is using a Cookie: ARRAffinity=c4b66198677464de573103f7aa267c33ea38617020514011cea4506e0a55d9d0; AppServiceAuthSession=EIVymV

Questions:

1. The problem is Mobile app documentation is it just provides
   instructions on how to use the SDK. I am unclear on how I would
   obtain the token issued by the app service.
2. Everyone knows how to obtain access tokens for Google
   and Twitter. Can they be used to access Azure API apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that API apps use the same built-in authentication as mobile apps. The basic flow looks like this:

1. Login to the app using provider credentials. This can be done using either a client-directed flow using your provider's SDK or can be done using a server-directed flow involving browser popups (i.e. the web view you mentioned). In the latter case, there is an endpoint at /.auth/login/ which is provided by App Service and manages the login flow for your app.
2. App Service will respond to your client app with a session token (a JWT).
3. You call into your APIs using the session token from #2. It is passed via the **x-zumo-auth** HTTP request header (it's named this way for legacy reasons).

The AppServiceAuthSession cookie you are seeing is the session cookie for when you use a browser to do authentication. ARRAffinity is an internal routing cookie used by App Service and is not related to auth.

If you're looking for more internal technical details on how the built-in App Service Authentication / Authorization works, check out my blog, starting with this post: http://cgillum.tech/2016/02/01/architecture-of-azure-app-service-authentication-authorization/

Comment: The problem is Mobile app documentation does not explain authorisation. A
If I have an access token for twitter, can I use it with my Azure API app?

Comment: Yes you can, using the LoginAsync overload that takes a JObject. I'm not sure where the docs are for this (they might need to be added/updated).  Basically, you need to pass a JSON object like {"access_token":"XXX", "access_token_secret": "YYY" }. I'll check around and see if there are any blog posts on this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just successfully obtained Azure Api App token using the WebAuthBroker. 
However the token starts with: 
token=7B22authenticationToken223A22eyJ0eXA
And I had to remove the part with 223A22. Why is that? 

Also just read your blog, The stuff about refreshing tokens is great! I haven't seen it anywhere else.

Comment: Weird, looks like an encoding issue where the '%' characters got dropped.  Those first few characters represent { and '"' characters because the token param is returning a JSON object.  Anyways, glad you got unblocked. Feel free to mark my answer as the accepted answer. :)

Comment: I basically run the WebAtuhBroker with the StartUrl of "/.auth/login/twitter" and EndURL of "/.auth/login/done". I got the token in the URI. Is that a good way to go about this process? 
The % characters were removed by me, I didn't realise that it was URI-encoded JSON.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you're basically doing the same thing that the mobile/App Service SDK does, and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!